# Why the entitymanager does not get autowired in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have an abstract repository class in which I used entitymanager and I want to initialize it with spring boot, but it gives an error that this object is null. What should I do? I used both @PersistenceContext on the entitymanager field and @EnableJpaRepositories on the main class, but the result is the same. What should I do?

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Transactional
@Repository
@Qualifier("personDAO")
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T> {
    public EntityManager em;
    @Transient
    protected Class clazz;

    public AbstractDAO(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
    public void persist(T model) {
        em.persist(model);
    }

    public void delete(T model) {
        em.remove(model);
    }

    public boolean deleteById(int id) {
        boolean result= em.createQuery("delete from "+clazz.getSimpleName()+ " o where o.id=" + id).executeUpdate() > 0;
        return result;
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return em.createQuery("select o from "+clazz.getSimpleName()+" o").getResultList();}

    public T findById(int id) {
        return (T) em.find(clazz, id);
    }
}
```

an example of its implementation:

```
public class SimpleDAOImpl extends SimpleDAO<Person> {
    public SimpleDAOImpl(Class<?> clazz) {
           this.clazz=Person.class;
    }
}
```

exception:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.persistence.EntityManager.persist(Object)" because "this.em" is null
    at org.isoft.repo.AbstractDAO.persist(AbstractDAO.java:29)
    at org.isoft.App.main(App.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: There should be an @Autowired tag on your entity manager if you want spring to auto wire, no? Spring won’t do it for you unless you ask :)

Comment: @backwardforward I used constructor injection, which no longer requires Autowired field. But I also tried your way, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I may be wrong because my understanding of spring is mediocre at best: but you injected noArgsConstructor, which will not autowire entity manager, so autowire the second constructor or instance itself

Comment: Can you add a concrete subclass to the question?

Comment: @BJagger it did not work. I don't know where the work comes from? I use intellij idea 2022. Does that mean it might have a bug?

Comment: @AMZ Your code is not compiling because no default constructor is available in the abstract class. Can you please review the implementation class?

Comment: @birca123 The class has a default constructor annotated with '@NoArgsConstructor'

Comment: Ok, I think you only need to add a setter for EntityManager and annotate it with @Autowired so Spring can inject it through the setter injection.

Comment: @birca123 I added it but unfortunately it doesn't work again

Comment: How do you instantiate SimpleDAOImpl?

Comment: @birca123 It worked. I didn't realize that when creating the object, we have to pass the entitymanager object to it again. Thank you

Comment: Great, I would suggest you remove `@NoArgsConstructor`, to prevent calling the constructor without dependencies. I prefer `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and making all dependencies final, in that case, Lombok generates a constructor for the final fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject some bean in abstract class for its implementation classes, you need to use Autowired annotation on the initialization method instead of a constructor like

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Transactional
@Repository
@Qualifier("personDAO")
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T> {
    public EntityManager em;
    @Transient
    protected Class clazz;

    @Autowired
    public init(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
    public void persist(T model) {
        em.persist(model);
    }

    public void delete(T model) {
        em.remove(model);
    }

    public boolean deleteById(int id) {
        boolean result= em.createQuery("delete from "+clazz.getSimpleName()+ " o where o.id=" + id).executeUpdate() > 0;
        return result;
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return em.createQuery("select o from "+clazz.getSimpleName()+" o").getResultList();}

    public T findById(int id) {
        return (T) em.find(clazz, id);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, Spring won't inject the bean and it will be null for implementations of this abstraction

Also you can inject this bean in every implementation of this class

Comment: it did not work. I don't know where the work comes from? I use intellij idea 2022. Does that mean it might have a bug?